# While connecting to leveldb it throws error of corrupt files

Tags: leveldb

While i tried connecting to my existing leveldb it is throwing the following error
"OpenError: Corruption: 18 missing files;"

It was working fine and i was able to fetch data, suddenly this error occurred and i am not able to fetch any data.
I don't want to do repair and loose the data.

Comment: Is this linux or windows? And what happened prior to corruption - power loss?